# Limiting data Inserts on database row

Tags: php, sql

Hello currently I'm working with this line of code:

```
    if( $get_display->level== "Nursery"){
        $lbl="Kinder";
        }
    else if( $get_display->level== "Kinder"){
        $lbl="Preparatory";
        }
    else if( $get_display->level== "Preparatory"){
        $lbl="Grade 1";
        }
    else if( $get_display->level== "Grade 1"){
        $lbl="Grade 2";
        }
     ******THE else if goes on but still the same*****
```

So I'm planning to automatically Pick a section depending on the students grade, I am planning to put this code in each of the if statements above. Like this:

```
    else if( $get_display->level== "Grade 1"){
        $lbl="Grade 2";
                 if($get_display->gpa => "88"){ 
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_section where level='$lbl' 
       and section_name="A"");
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
               $sname = $row['section_name'];
               }else if($get_display->gpa => "80"){ 
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_section where level='$lbl' 
       and section_name="B"");
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
               $sname = $row['section_name'];
       }else if($get_display->gpa => "75"){ 
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_section where level='$lbl' 
       and section_name="C"");
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
               $sname = $row['section_name'];                        
                    }
        }
```

And **$sname** would be used here:

```
    <input type="text"  name="levele" value="<?php echo $sname;?>">
```

My main problem now is what if **section a** is full , it should automatically insert to **section b** right? how should i be able to do that? and should i add a field in my **tbl_section** to count the student who are in? And if i would tamper my DB how should it look?would appreciate any help. 
(pls don't mention my DB is very compromised, already know that just a simple project but i will implement mysql_real_escape_string() later on, don't have the knowledge on mysqli yet.)

EDIT: **section a and b** are just field names in my Database here is what **tbl_section** looks like.

```
     section_id (int)
     section_name(vchar)(default names are A,B,C and cannot be changed)
     sy (school year) 
     adviser_id
     level
```

Sorry first time to show my db here hope this is correct.

Comment: I don't know what section a nor section b is, what your application is doing or what your database looks like...

Comment: A tiny suggestion unrelated to your question is please look into switch statements instead of all your elseif for your first block of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just `SELECT` a `section_name` that is not full:

```
SELECT section_name, COUNT(*) 
FROM tbl_section 
WHERE level='$lbl' 
GROUP BY section_name
HAVING COUNT(*) < 80 
LIMIT 1
```

You also need to stop using `mysql_` functions as they are [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com) and are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Also, I would rewrite your snippet above to condense code like so:

```
elseif( $get_display->level== "Grade 1" ) {
    $lbl="Grade 2";

    if( $get_display->gpa => "88" ) {
        $section_name = 'A';
    }
    elseif( $get_display->gpa => "80" ) {
        $section_name = 'B';
    }
    elseif( $get_display->gpa => "75" ) {
        $section_name = 'C';                      
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_section where level='$lbl' and section_name='$section_name' LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $sname = $row['section_name'];  
}
```

Comment: Sorry first time i encountered count() what does `HAVING COUNT(*) < 80 LIMIT 1` mean?

Comment: @Tony `COUNT` is used for counting the number of results that would typically be returned for that query. You can test this by running `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_section`.

Comment: Thanks, do you think that i should add a field on my tbl_section for example **IN** and i could count that? and also that every time i enroll a student in a specific section the value should increase. I'm unsure how to perform that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Tony You should not store values that can be calculated. Which means, if you can do a `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`, there is no point to store the number of students in a section

Comment: @Tony In plain English, you are asking the database to give you the count of each section where level is `$lbl` with a count less than 80. However, where are you storing your student list?